# Block layout doesn't not flow correctly

Tags: css, layout, block

[image]

This is what happens when the first column is relatively higher.
I am using float:left.

[image]

Wired thing happens when the third column is height, float operates correctly.
How can I achieve this? I used inline-block, which does what I want, but the framework I am using is using float left and is responsive design. So I dont want to break the rule.

The code I use:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 metro-post">
                    <figure>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_640x430/public/coffee-ban.jpg" class="feature-img-md img-responsive" alt="feature-image"></a>
                    </figure>
                    <footer class="post-info">#December 12, 2013</footer>
                    <a href="#" class="link-sl-second"><h1 class="link-style-xsm">People Blown Over In The Streets As Storm Ivar Hits Norway</h1></a>
                    <p>People Christmas shopping in downtown Aalesund had troubles crossing the street today. The storm "Ivar" was blowing things and people around. One man blew off the sidewalk and into the street in an intersection downtown Aalesund earlier. troubles crossing the street today. The storm "Ivar" was blowing things and people around. One man blew off the sidewalk and into the street in an intersection downtown Aalesund earlier.</p>
                    <div class="post-share">
                        <a href="#"><span>Facebook</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span>Twitter</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span>Pinterest</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span>Google+</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span>Reddit</span></a>
                    </div>
</div> <!-- end of metro-post -->



.metro-post {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        overflow:hidden; 
        /*float: none;
        display: inline-block;*/
}

.col-md-4 {
width: 33.33333333333333%;
float:left
}
```

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `<div class="clearfix"></div>` between the third and fourth column.
Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/myTerminal/xb94J/ demonstrates the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue, and therefore there are more than one ways to do it.

I'll start with my **favorite one**. If you don't care about IE8 and before, then the easiest and most elegant way is to use CSS3 'nth-child' selector:

```
.metro-post {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.metro-post:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

**Other** ways are a little bit more tricky because they involve HTML changes too, and in your case they will not work because you have different number of columns for different resolutions.

Just for the sake of answering, one way would be to wrap every n(chosen by you) number of columns in a clearfixed wrapper which acts like a row, like so:

```
<div class="clearfix">    
    <div class="col">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">    
    <div class="col">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Or a little bit simpler to add a .clear in between each n number of columns, like so:

```
<div class="col">
...
</div>
<div class="col">
...
</div>
<div class="col">
...
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="col">
...
</div>
<div class="col">
...
</div>
<div class="col">
...
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

where :

```
.clear {
   clear:both;
}

.clearfix:after {
   display: block;
   visibility: hidden;
   height: 0;
   line-height: 0;
   clear: both;
   content: '.';
}
```